# Dimline Label Position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to move the labels on the bottom set of metrics to the end of each line. The metrics I need to change are the second set under the comment %metrics below flume. However, I have only been able to get it above the line and slightly to the right rather than at the end of the line. I'm not sure what label style will give me what I need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\title{Beji and Battjes 1993 Experiment}
\date{September 2021}
%this was used to create ground symbol
\newcommand\Ground{%
\mathbin{\text{\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,yscale=0.6,xscale=0.5]
\draw (0,2ex) to (0,0) node[ground,rotate=-90,xshift=.65ex] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Figure \ref{flume} is a schematic diagram for the Beji experiments
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.15in,y=2.67in]
%bottom of flume
\draw[black, very thick] ( 0.00, 0.00) -- ( 6.00, 0.00) -- (12.00, 0.30) -- (14.00, 0.30) -- (17.00, 0.00) -- (18.95, 0.00) -- (37.70, 0.75);
%beach
\draw[black, very thick] (18.95, 0.00) -- (37.70, 0.0) -- (37.70, 0.75) -- cycle;
%some additional lines
\draw[black, very thick] (12.00, 0.0) -- (12.00, 0.30);
\draw[black, very thick] (14.00, 0.0) -- (14.00, 0.30);
\draw[black, very thick] ( 6.00, 0.00) -- (17.00, 0.00);
\draw[black, thick, double] ( 0.00, 0.00) -- (0.00, 0.4);
\draw[black, very thick, decorate, decoration={coil,aspect=0,amplitude=4.0, segment length=12}] (0.0,0.4) -- (2.0,0.4);
\draw[black, very thick] (2.0,0.4) -- (28.95,0.4);
%location of gauges
\filldraw[black] (6.0,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {1};
\draw[black, dashed] (6.0,0.6) -- (6.0,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (10.8,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {2};
\draw[black, dashed] (10.8,0.6) -- (10.8,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (12.8,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {3};
\draw[black, dashed] (12.8,0.6) -- (12.8,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (13.8,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {4};
\draw[black, dashed] (13.8,0.6) -- (13.8,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (14.8,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {5};
\draw[black, dashed] (14.8,0.6) -- (14.8,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (16.0,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {6};
\draw[black, dashed] (16.0,0.6) -- (16.0,0.4);
\filldraw[black] (17.6,0.6) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {7};
\draw[black, dashed] (17.6,0.6) -- (17.6,0.4);

%metrics above gauges
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(6,0.7)}{(10.8,0.7)}{4.8}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(10.8,0.7)}{(12.8,0.7)}{2}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(12.8,0.7)}{(13.8,0.7)}{1}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(13.8,0.7)}{(14.8,0.7)}{1}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(14.8,0.7)}{(16,0.7)}{1.2}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(16,0.7)}{(17.6,0.7)}{1.6}

%metrics below flume  
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(0,-0.1)}{(6,-0.1)}{6}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(6,-0.1)}{(12,-0.1)}{6}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(12,-0.1)}{(14,-0.1)}{2}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(14,-0.1)}{(17,-0.1)}{3}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(17,-0.1)}{(18.95,-0.1)}{1.95}
\dimline[label style={above}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(18.95,-0.1)}{(37.7,-0.1)}{18.75}

\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(0,-0.2)}{(6,-0.2)}{6}
\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(6,-0.2)}{(12,-0.2)}{12}
\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(12,-0.2)}{(14,-0.2)}{14}
\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(14,-0.2)}{(17,-0.2)}{17}
\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(17,-0.2)}{(18.95,-0.2)}{18.95}
\dimline[label style={above right}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(18.95,-0.2)}{(37.7,-0.2)}{37.7}

%metrics on side of flume
\dimline[label style={sloped=false}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(-1,0)}{(-1,0.4)}{0.4}
\dimline[label style={sloped=false}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(39,0)}{(39,0.75)}{0.75}

%measurements throughout diagram
\node (n1) at (11,0.15) {0.3};
\node (n2) at (9,0.2) {1:20};
\node (n3) at (16,0.2) {1:10};
\node (n4) at (26,0.2) {1:25};
\node (n5) at (35,0.175) {Beach};
\node (n6) at (-1,0.45) {Wave-board};
\node (n7) at (26,0.45) {Still water level};
\node (n8) at (22,0.43) {$\nabla$};
\node (n9) at (3,0.45) {$\longrightarrow$};
\node (n10) at (22,0.40) {$\Ground{}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Definition sketch of wave flume and gauges.
\label{flume}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you found an answer to your previous question about the fluid/ground symbol :) if you want you can merge that account to your current one to add that question to your list, by clicking `flag` below the post and choosing `in need of moderator intervention`, then add a short message that you want to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the following code

adjust the `pos` per choice

adjust font per choice --

[image]

```
%metrics below flume  
\dimline[label style={pos=0.9}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0, ]{(0,-0.1)}{(6,-0.1)}{\small 6}
\dimline[label style={pos=0.9}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(6,-0.1)}{(12,-0.1)}{\small 6}
\dimline[label style={pos=0.9}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(12,-0.1)}{(14,-0.1)}{\small 2}
\dimline[label style={pos=0.9}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(14,-0.1)}{(17,-0.1)}{\small 3}
\dimline[label style={pos=0.5}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(17,-0.1)}{(18.95,-0.1)}{\small 1.95}
\dimline[label style={pos=0.9}, extension start length=0, extension end length=0]{(18.95,-0.1)}{(37.7,-0.1)}{\small 18.75}
```

[image]